# PHP: Defining a Constant to Prevent Direct Access

Tags: php

I want to prevent direct access my `install.php` file, unless the user has gone through the steps of filling information and submitting the form.

**install/index.php:**

```
define("ACCESS", true);

// HTML form to take to install.php
```

**install/install.php:**

```
if (!defined("ACCESS")) {
    echo "You cannot access this page directly.";
    exit();
} else {
    // Run SQL Queries
    echo "Database installation successful.";
}
```

Obviously this won't work. How I can get this concept to work?

*Additional questions:*
What is the best practice for this?
Should I be using a constant or a function?

Comment: Explain your process more. It's difficult to make a recommendation for *best practice* without more information.

Comment: Your concept there will only work if you use "include()". Best practice is difficult without knowing the workflow of the application.

Comment: So this code works well with an include();, but are there other methods I should know if I chose not to use an include();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but instead of having the user access `install.php` directly, you would `include` it from `index.php` which defines the constant.

This way, you control when they view that script by having `index.php` load it when appropriate, and they still cannot access it directly because of your check for the defined constant.